# Qt Widget setFont() works on Windows but not OS X?

Tags: qt

I have a class(such MyWidget) derived from QWidget. I write some codes below:

```
// qStr is QString type;
// iSize is int type;
QFont font(qStr, iSize, QFont::Normal);
myWidget->setFont(font);
myWidget->update();
```

Those codes work well on Windows but not OS X. What could be the cause of the problem ?

Update  -------------------

My colleague has just removed the feature and it means that 'setFont' is not allowed now. So I give up .

Comment: What is value of `qStr` in second case (on OS X)?

Answer (score 1):

It may occur that some Style properties are not displayed correctly depending on the OS. It seems that Apple thinks it would interfere with the general look and feel of Mac OS. You could try using the [StyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) class instead of setting the font directly.

Comment: It seems that the cause of this problem is Chinese fonts, not the function 'setFont'.   Thank you, I will  try to solve the new problem.